# Validate context menu item for each tab

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, safari-extension

I am developing a simple Safari extension that adds a context menu item, which when clicked will let me perform a specific task with the data on the page current. In my `injected-scripts.js` I have a function `validForContextMenu` which determines wether or not the context menu should be displayed for the clicked tab. Along with this function I am dispatching the following message to my `global.html` in order to let it know if the tab should display my context menu item or not.

```
safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("validate", validForContextMenu());
```

In `global.html` I am doing the following to listen to message, store the data returned by `injected-scripts.js`, and perform the actual validation:

```
var contextMenuDisabled = true;

function respondToMessage(theMessageEvent) {
    if (theMessageEvent.name === "validate") {
        contextMenuDisabled = theMessageEvent.message;
    }
}

safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.addEventListener("message", respondToMessage, false);

function validateCommand(event) {
    event.target.disabled = contextMenuDisabled;
}
safari.application.addEventListener("validate", validateCommand, false);
```

This all works out quite fine apart from the fact that the validation is only performed once, and only for the tab/page being frontmost at the time my extension loads. If that page is valid for context menu, then so will all other pages and vice versa. I would like the validation to be performed individually for each of Safaris tabs.

Ca this be done? Am I missing something on the way injected scripts or dispatched messages works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `global.html` is singleton and therefore your have only one variable `contextMenuDisabled` for all tabs. Safari has the special API for this task - [safari.self.tab.setContextMenuEventUserInfo](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/AddingContextualMenuItems/AddingContextualMenuItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH4-SW1).

I use the next code in my extension. In inject.js:

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', onContextMenu, false);

function onContextMenu(ev) {
  var UserInfo = {
    pageId: pageId
  };
  var sel = document.getSelection();
  if (sel && !sel.isCollapsed)
    UserInfo.isSel = true;

  safari.self.tab.setContextMenuEventUserInfo(ev, UserInfo);
};
```

In global.js:

```
safari.application.addEventListener('validate', onValidate, false);

function onValidate(ev) {
  switch (ev.command) {
  case 'DownloadSel':
    if (!ev.userInfo || !ev.userInfo.isSel)
      ev.target.disabled = true;
    break;
  };
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was after! It makes perfect sense that the `global.html` is a singleton, unique instances for each tab would have limited the extension possibilities in a number of ways.